# Is it possible to apply the box shadow properties separately?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I am applying styles to my Vue component and I ran into an issue with the box-shadow property. Is it possible to set the box shadow styles separately like this - boxShadowHorizontal, boxShadowVertical, boxShadowBlur, and so on?

Please check the attached screenshot. The padding and margin properties works fine. Also, I have added border styles similarly. But Boxshadow doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me if it is possible to apply the box-shadow styles like this or if there is a different way?

[image]

Comment: You can move the origin of a shadow around, but it's the same shadow. What happens to one side affects the rest of the shadow. So if you move it down, the top will be smaller and bottom larger. But they are the same shadow, you're not applying different shadow effects to different sides. Can't be red on top and green on bottom, unless you use two separate elements (with different shadows) and glue them together.

Comment: @tao, actually it's not about applying different shadows on different sides. I know it will be the same shadow on all sides. What I wanted to know was that in the box-shadow property can I set values for horizontal, vertical, spread, blur, and color separately instead of all within one box-shadow property? For example, if you consider the Border property you can set it as - border: 1px solid red; in one line and also separately like - border-width: 1px, border-style:solid, border-color: red; and that is what I was looking for in case of box-shadow.

Comment: The answer is still no. `border`, `margin`, `padding` are shorthand properties. Which means they are composed of other properties: `border-top`, `border-right`, etc (which, in turn, are also shorthand properties of `border-{side}-width`, `border-{side}-style` and `border-{side}-color`). This is not the case with `box-shadow`, which is not a shorthand property. You can only set its value by specifying all of the required values at once, as they don't have individual CSS properties.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I would have to find a way to set the values of the box-shadow all at once.

Answer (score 0):

MDN is a very good place to find information like that:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

That being said, there is no official way to do what you asked for, but you could use custom variables to achieve a similar result:

```js
styles.boxShadow = "var(--boxShadowHorizontal, 0) var(--boxShadowVertical, 0) var(--boxShadowBlur, 0) var(--boxShadowSpread, 0) var(--boxShadowColor)"

styles["--boxShadowHorizontal"] = "2px";
styles["--boxShadowVertical"] = "0";
styles["--boxShadowBlur"] = "1em";
styles["--boxShadowSpread"] = "0";
styles["--boxShadowColor"] = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
```

Keep in mind though, that you are loosing the flexibility to add multiple box-shadows this way. Also, there is the `inset` option for box-shadows, which is not available via those variables right now.

---

```css
.example {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: 2em;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow: var(--boxShadowHorizontal, 0) var(--boxShadowVertical, 0) var(--boxShadowBlur, 0) var(--boxShadowSpread, 0) var(--boxShadowColor, currentColor);
  
  
  /* now you can use variables to define box shadow */
  --boxShadowHorizontal: 5px;
  --boxShadowBlur: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I will try out the custom variables. Otherwise, I guess I can only use the boxShadow property and add all the values there instead of separately defining boxShadowHorizontal, boxShadowVertical, etc.

Comment: You're just changing the origin of the box shadow. You're not applying different shadows on different sides, which is what the question asks. In other words, this question asks: can the shadow be red on left side and green on top side? The answer is NO. It's the same shadow on all sides. You can play with it and move it around, but any change to it will affect all of it (all four sides), there's no way to limit it to being applied to only one side.

Comment: @tao, well then I misread the question. To me the question does not mention different shadow colors on the different sides in any way. It says " Is it possible to set the box shadow styles separately like this - boxShadowHorizontal, boxShadowVertical, boxShadowBlur, and so on?"

Comment: It's not about colour *per-se*. But it could easily be read as: can I have a shadow of `100px` on left/right and `0px` on top/bottom? Because each side is a separate variable. The answer is *"Definitely not. You can have the same shadow on all sides and you can move its origin."*

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to implemented it using the following code -

```
let boxShadowHorizontal = widgetStyles.boxshadow.value.horizontal;
let boxShadowVertical = widgetStyles.boxshadow.value.vertical;
let boxShadowBlur = widgetStyles.boxshadow.value.blur ;
let boxShadowSpread = widgetStyles.boxshadow.value.spread;
let boxShadowColor = widgetStyles.boxshadow.value.color;
let boxShadowPosition = widgetStyles.boxshadow.value.position;

styles.boxShadow = boxShadowHorizontal+'px' + ' ' + boxShadowVertical+'px' + ' ' + boxShadowBlur+'px' + ' ' + boxShadowSpread+'px' + ' ' + boxShadowColor + boxShadowPosition;
```

I am not sure if this is the best approach but it seems to work for my use case. Any other suggestions are welcome. Thank you!